# Error - post request in node.js

Tags: node.js, odata

I have a odata service which will update the record in my backend system once i make a post call using a json body.

Below is the code, which i am using but when initiating the request from my frontend application i am getting "Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off" exception -

```
function oDataCall(endPoint, response) {
var username1 = "xxx"; 
var password1 = "pass";
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(username1 + ":" +password1).toString("base64");
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
"Vbeln":"0010001825",
"Vkbur":"HO"
,"Vkgrp":"001"
});
var http = require('https');
var options1 = {
  host: 'host',
  port: '443',
  path: '/odata/SAP/ZGW_SALESORDERAPP_SRV/CreateSoSet',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 };
  // Set up the request
  var post_req = http.request(options1, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
     });
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Error message: " + e.message);
    response(false);
 });
  // post the data
 post_req.write(jsonObject);
  post_req.end();
   }
```

error - document.write("Please wait ...");

Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.

Comment: Does your browser support JS or is it turned off?

Comment: yes, i am using chrome browser and JS is enabled.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, but w/o any way to poke and prod I'm not sure how to help. Sounds like the problem is on the client side, either in your code, or in your client, neither of which we know anything about ¯\(°_o)/¯